# How to handle multi device authentication with JWT spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jwt

I want to implement JWT security in my project which should allow login from the web as well as mobile (multiple devices).

Comment: Hi Kushi, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have implemented JWT security and its works fine for the single device login.

Comment: That is nice. In order to receieve an answer, you have to ask a question. Simply put which things you have now, and ask about what is not working as expected.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried JWT integration in the spring boot project its working fine. My requirement is to enable login with multiple devices, I found this is to be handled with the device type. I tried to search many online resources to find the solution but not getting any relevant reference.

Comment: You have to put your code or steps you tried, what you implemented, what error you are getting. inside your question section. If possible also include code snippet of relevant part of your project.